# How to install tensorflow-text=2.8.*?

Tags: tensorflow2.0

**I want to install tensorflow-text with version of 2.8.x.**

First when I use:

```
pip install tensorflow-text',
```

I can only installed the version of 2.6.x.

And then when I use:

```
pip install -U "tensorflow-text==2.8.*" ,
```

it said that:

> ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement
> tensorflow-text==2.8.* (from versions: 0.1.0rc2, 0.1.0, 1.0.0b2,
> 1.15.0rc0, 1.15.1, 2.0.0rc0, 2.0.1, 2.1.0rc0, 2.2.0rc2, 2.2.0, 2.2.1, 2.3.0rc1, 2.3.0, 2.4.0b0, 2.4.0rc0, 2.4.0rc1, 2.4.1, 2.4.2, 2.4.3, 2.5.0rc0, 2.5.0, 2.6.0rc0, 2.6.0) ERROR: No matching distribution found for tensorflow-text==2.8.*

Comment: According to library issues there is [an issue](https://github.com/tensorflow/text/issues/841) with tf-2.8.x macros and tf-text, also with [the recent linux version](https://github.com/tensorflow/text/issues/878). So, I would suggest to downgrade tf version and try tf-text on that version, If it would be possible.

Comment: What are the `Python version` and `TensorFlow version` installed in your 'System'? Because from your `Installation wizard Error` I can see that; the `pip module` is installing `tf-text-2.6.x` because I think you are using `TensorFlow==2.6.x`. So, for Access to the version `tf-text v2.8.x` kindly upgrade your `TensorFlow` to on or above `v2.8.0` Because When we install `TF Text` with `pip install`, NOTE: The `version` of `TensorFlow` you are running, as you should specify the corresponding `version` of `TF Text.`